# Any way to change the default folder icon?

Tags: 13.04, style

I've tried 'assogiate' but contains only about the file types, no folder option is available.I don't want to install any theme or change folder icon individually.

My bad, didn't include at first: I want to add icon of my choice.

Any Help is Appreciated !

Answer (score 13):

### To Change The Default Folder Icon

1. **Right click on the folder whose default icon you want to change.**
2. **Choose(click on) Properties.**

   *you will get the 'change-icon-Properties window' similliar to the one below in the image.*

   [image: change-icon-properties window]
3. **Click on the default folder icon**

   *It is the icon in the top left corner of your 'change-icon-Properties window'.*

   [image: icon position]

   *You should click on this icon*

   [image: default folder-icon]

   4.**This should open up your file browser asking you to select your custom icon.**

   **Browse to your desired image and double click on it.**

   #### That's it!!

   *Should you still have any difficulty following the instructions please refer to this youtube video*

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-w21GsLdHfk

Answer (score 4):

Grab the Unity Tweak Tool, and select "Icons" under the Appearance section.

[image]

You should be able to do it from there.

If you want to be able to switch an individual default icon, I read in this [Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2129833) that the default icon is designated in this file:

```
/usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

Look for the line that reads:

```
Icon=system-file-manager
```

Try adjusting that (to your new icon file) and see if it helps.

Comment: Actually,want to add icon of my choice.

Comment: @Terminal edit made

Comment: sorry, didn't find "nautilus-folder-handler.desktop"

Comment: @Terminal How about `/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`?